differences between /usr/sbin/nologin and optional encrypted password field '*' in /etc/passwd
Just getting to know about password management on my distro I came across the /etc/passwd file.
I found out that the 'optional encrypted password' field in a line for an account is based on these the below documented lines.

If the password field is a lower-case x, then the encrypted password is actually stored in the shadow(5) file instead; there must be a corresponding line in the /etc/shadow file, or else the user account is invalid.
If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

These snippets of man passwd.5 say enough about logging privileges for users. When I cat /etc/passwd, I don't see any * but an appended /usr/sbin/nologin to the individual user/process lines. An example:
saned:x:125:133::/var/lib/saned:/usr/sbin/nologin

Doing man nologin says something like this:

The nologin command displays a message that an account is not available and exits non-zero. It is intended as a replacement shell field for accounts that have been disabled.

The questions:

Are * and /usr/sbin/login with x replacements for each other?
Does nologin limits the user to log in by any means (including the ones referred to as 'by any means')?
What are the differences b/w a user not being able to log in and user account that has been disabled?



No, one creates an impossible password, one sets an unusable shell. 2. It prevents them from running a login shell, but they can still be used to execute commands ssh $host $cmd 3. See the answer to 2. (Fellow mods: This is deliberately a "comment answer" becuase I disagree with the OpenAI deal.)


@Panki thanks. What OpenAI deal?
